# How to prove that there are infinite number of magic squares consisting of only prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions

> Question: For every positive integer $M \geq 3$, there exists an $M \times M$ magic square all $M^2$ terms of which are prime.

I don't know how to do it. All I feel is that the Green-Tao theorem can help as it shows the existence of infinitely many primes in AP and for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Also there's a property of $M \times M$ magic square that a square exists using the numbers $\{1,2, \cdots , M^2\}$

But the thing is that I can't find any relationship between these. 
All I could think of is that if a magic square can be created with some $\{0, 2d, \cdots, (n-1)d\}$, for all $d\in \mathbb{N}$, then we could have chosen some $a$ for which terms of the sequence $\{id\}_{0 \leq i \leq (n-1)}$ would become $\{a+id\}$ for the same $i$. 
But it's quite of no progress.

Can someone help me out? I don't know how to prove it. Please provide with rigor.

Comment: I remember it slightly different : Dirichlet proved that every arithmetic progression $an+b$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ contains infinite many primes and the Green Tao theorem states that we can produce arbitary long arithmetic progressions containing only primes (I think the case of consecutive primes remains open, but we do not need this here). This would immediately imply that we can produce infinite many magic squares even of every size containing only primes.

Comment: If you can use Green-Tao theorem, first construct magic square with ${1,\cdots ,M^2}$ and $M^2$ primes in arithmetic progression then substitute $i$th number with $i$th prime in arithmetic progression.